# Match quantified word character as many times in a group

Tags: javascript, regex, pcre, regex-group

This drives me crazy. The string looks like following:

```
actionname {componentOne, componentTwo, componentThree}
```

in this example I should have matched in a groups `actionname`, `componentOne`, `componentTwo` and `componentThree`. Of course, *exact number* of "components" inside brackets *I shall not know*, it is at least one but may be multiple.

I tried:

```
\w+
```

beginner level, matches all, including `actionname`. This could suit the purpose, but there are better solutions,

```
^actionname\s*{\s*(\w+)+\s*.*}
```

bloody hell, matches only one, in this case `componentOne`, even I've used quantifier for matching group `(\w+)+`,

```
^actionname\s*{\s*(\w+)(:?\s*\,\s*(\w+)|\s*})
```

the failure of this is the point. I'm able to expand the match to the second component, **but only declaratively** i.e. I cannot expand group to as many words (delimited by `,` with optional spaces) as there may be. All regexes presented are with **gm** modifiers.

How to get correct result?

Special thanks to at least basic explanation, not only working solution.

Comment: Try `\w+(?=[^{}]*})` or use `\G` like `(?:actionname {|\G(?!\A))(\w+)[, ]*`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/2Tzv2p/1

Comment: Thanks. It is working. But I should learn this not only paste the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to go since PCER has every thing we need here. First using a positive lookahead:

```
\w+(?=[^{}]*})
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/2Tzv2p/1)

This is a handy workaround. However it all depends on your input string. It says match word characters that are followed by (not necessarily immediately) a closing brace `}` without matching a brace `[{}]` while reaching it.

The other option is `\G`. `\G` metacharacter exists for those kinds of match that should start from a specific point. `\G` means resume match from where the previous match ends or from beginning of string (as `\A`):

```
(?:actionname {|\G(?!\A))(\w+)[, ]*
```

This regex beginning point is where it sees `actionname`. It doesn't choose the other side of alternation since we disabled `\G` from matching beginning of string using a negative lookahead `(?!\A)`. After matching `actionname` it tries to capture word characters and matches optional commas and spaces after it. If `g` is enabled it resumes match from where previous match ends. So It captures all those words.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/XWJJ7n/1)

Comment: Revo, if you can get this regex working in actual JavaScript code, this would be a really great answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand but the first approach should return desired matches in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get repeating capture groups of arbitrary/unknown length to work in JavaScript.  One workaround would be take advantage of that your expected input string is a word followed by a CSV string in brackets.  We can use regex to isolate the leading word and CSV string, then split that CSV content, or arbitrary length, into a single array.

```js
var input = "actionname {componentOne, componentTwo, componentThree}";
var re = /^(\S+)\s+\{([^}]+)\}$/g;
var m;

m = re.exec(input);
results = [];
if (m) {
    results.push(m[1]);
    results.push(m[2].split(/, /));
    console.log(results.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. as far as I see `componentTwo` is not in the group? Or maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Look at the match information on the right side. actionname, componentOne and componentThree are isolated.

Comment: @MilošĐakonović LOL maybe I'm wrong :-)  ... didn't see that, the demo has the same problem as JavaScript.  I edited my answer.